# Choosing layout folder for supporting all devices

Tags: android, layout, screen

I got a problem related to the layout folder for some device.
So at first I had `layout` and `layout-large` folder. I only have 3 xml files for layout inside of these layouts.
`layout` folder has xml files with using Eclipse configuration of Galaxy Nexus 4.65" (720x1280 xhdpi)
`layout-large` folder has xml files using Eclipse configuration of 5.1" WVGA (800x480 mdpi)

I tested it on a small Samsung Galaxy Youth 3.3" (320x480), and it's using `layout` folder... I don't really understand about screen res, I read it in google doc but until now I don't really get enough of it. Google Nexus configuration looked fit for small screen so I chose it without enough understanding in resolution or screen size. Somehow, it fit well in my Galaxy Youth.

While for larger screen device I depend on `layout-large` folder, so I tested it with Galaxy Tab 7". It fit well too. 
Problem arise when I tested it with Galaxy Note 2 and Galaxy Note 4 ..  (for other devices I didn't test because I don't have them).
Galaxy Note 2 and Galaxy Note 4 seems to use `layout` folder not the large one (I'm sure it'll fit well in my `layout-large`).

I actually want 320x480 or smaller screen size devices to all use `layout` and any devices with larger screen should use `layout-large`. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOU CAN USE CODE TO SELECT YOUR DESIRED layout for specific smallest-WIDTH of DEVICE..IN

onCreate:

```
   Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

    if (config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 480) {

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_LARGE);
    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }
```

the Document  say about ( sw NUMBER dp) format :" The exact point of this switch will depend on your particular design—maybe you need a 720dp width for your tablet layout, maybe 600dp is enough, or 480dp, or some number between these. "
so you can put in res :

res/layout/main_activity.xml

res/layout-sw480dp/main_activity.xml

Comment: is it safe to use programmatic way like this ? , i read before in one of discussion here that it's not a good way. but i'd give it a try if i am still stuck.

Comment: I edit my answer ;i have not use that solution but you can try it and I hope that will help you;

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://stefan222devel.blogspot.sk/2012/10/android-screen-densities-sizes.html
There is more information about screen sizes and densities of android devices

Comment: it's a bunch of important information but it's still make no sense for me because there are some attributes there and what i care is only about screen size. whether its small, medium, large, or xlarge.  I only need to use proper layout based on its screen size.. i am using only 1 drawable mdpi folder. i dont use other drawable folder.